# DirectMode with Devart and FluentNHibernate and Oracle 10g

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, oracle10g, windows-7-x64, devart

I have a **Windows x64** installed on my machine, of course Oracle hadn't made a Driver for using their client in **`Oracle10g`**, this is seems to be a huge problem for me (stop whining)....

***`So i actually have to connect to DB with Direct Mode.`***

This is the way it works:

```
  OracleConnectionStringBuilder oraCsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder {
            Direct = true,
            Server = "xxx",
            Port = 1521,
            Sid = "xxx",
            UserId = "xxx",
            Password = "xxx"
        };
        OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(oraCsb.ConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

        const string myInsertQuery = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID = 1";
        OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(myInsertQuery) { Connection = myConnection };
        myConnection.Open();

        try {
            var source = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        } finally {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Actually this way it's works.

But here is my problem how to Integrate it into FluentNHibernate?

How to use it in here?

```
     _configuration = Fluently.Configure().Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10   .ConnectionString(@"server=xxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx;SID=xxx;port=1521;Direct=True;")
 .UseReflectionOptimizer()
 .AdoNetBatchSize(5000)
 .ShowSql().FormatSql())
```

How to make it work without a *`OracleClient (for 10g)`*?

Answer (score 0):

The NHibernate runtime support and [Direct Mode](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?directmode.html) features are included in the Professional Edition of [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/). There is an example of compiling NHibernate sources to add support for dotConnect provider: http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/nhibernate_and_oracle.html.

Also we recommend you to pay attention to [Entity Developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/) for NHibernate (and Professional) which supports ADO.NET providers to create an NHibernate model and generate classes and mapping for them.

Comment: There is an example of how to use it in FluentNh?

Comment: I have 4.2.85 EF LinqConn I haven't purchased the NH ver how can you help me with that?

Comment: 1. There is a "Fluent NHibernate" template for NHibernate models in Entity Developer Professional (or NHibernate Edition): http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/entitydeveloper.chm (do Properties > Unblock if its content is blocked in your environment) > ORM Support > NHibernate > Generation > Model Generation Templates > Fluent NHibernate Template.

Comment: 2. Please refer to http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ordering.html . If you have any questions about ordering the product, contact our Sales department: http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html .